# Test automation card payment in flutter app that uses adyen with appium?

Tags: flutter, appium, ui-automation, webdriver-io, adyen

I'm using adyen_dropin plugin within my flutter app to manage payments. For the payment flow im trying to run an automation test that should enter card values and proceed to pay.
[See the screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2pwu.png)

The automation im writing using appium and webdriver.io.
and following is a test script that run.

```
const { expect, browser, $ } = require('@wdio/globals')
const screenPayment = require('../pageobjects/payments.page')

    describe('Launch app and proceed to payments', () => {
        it('Click on Basket counter icon and Proceed on payment flow', async () => {
            await screenPayment.clickProceedToPayment();
        })
    })
```

The page model is

```
const find = require('appium-flutter-finder');
const assert = require('assert');

class PaymentsPage{
    //click on basket icon in bottom navigation
    async clickProceedToPayment(){
        

        const checkoutButton = find.byText("Checkout Now");
        await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', checkoutButton);
        assert.strictEqual(await driver.getElementText(checkoutButton), 'Checkout Now');
        await driver.elementClick(checkoutButton);

        const proceedButton = find.byText("Proceed to Payment");
        await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', proceedButton);
        assert.strictEqual(await driver.getElementText(proceedButton), 'Proceed to Payment');
        await driver.elementClick(proceedButton);

        const contexts = await driver.getContexts();
        console.log('Available contexts now: ', contexts);

        await driver.switchContext('FLUTTER');

        const modalSheetTitle = find.byText("PAYMENT METHODS");
        await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', modalSheetTitle);  
        assert.strictEqual(await driver.getElementText(modalSheetTitle), 'PAYMENT METHODS');
       
        // const creditcardOption = find.byText("Credit Card");
        // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', creditcardOption);   
        // assert.strictEqual(await driver.getElementText(creditcardOption), 'Credit Card');
        // await driver.elementClick(creditcardOption);

        const cardPayTitle = find.byText("CREDIT CARD");
        await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', cardPayTitle);  
        assert.strictEqual(await driver.getElementText(cardPayTitle), 'CREDIT CARD');
        

        // const cardNumberField = find.byValueKey("app:id/editText_cardNumber");
        // // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', cardNumberField);   
        // await driver.waitFor(cardNumberField);
        // await driver.tap(cardNumberField);
        // await driver.enterText('5555 5555 5555 4444');

        // const expiryDateField = find.byValueKey("app:id/editText_expiryDate");
        // // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', expiryDateField);
        // await driver.waitFor(expiryDateField);   
        // await driver.tap(expiryDateField);
        // await driver.enterText('03/2030');

        // const cvcField = find.byValueKey("app:id/editText_securityCode");
        // // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', cvcField);   
        // await driver.waitFor(cvcField);
        // await driver.tap(cvcField);
        // await driver.enterText('737');

        // const cardHolderField = find.byValueKey("app:id/editText_cardHolder");
        // // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', cardHolderField);
        // await driver.waitFor(cardHolderField);   
        // await driver.tap(cardHolderField);
        // await driver.enterText('Corporate');

        // const payButton = find.byValueKey("app:id/payButton");
        // // await driver.execute('flutter:waitFor', payButton);   
        // await driver.waitFor(payButton);
        // await driver.tap(payButton);
    }
}
module.exports = new PaymentsPage()
```

When in run the test script it does not identify the elements in adyen dropin (the commented lines for card payment fields). the log shows Available contexts now:  [ 'NATIVE_APP', 'FLUTTER' ].

How can i properly format or update this test to work ?